# Trying to get W10 kb5034441 installed. The Windows RE image was not found

Tags: partitioning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkFoE.png)I am not a 'super'user.  Attempting to successfully update W10 Pro using various tutorials with no luck.  Read somewhere that the update only applies to Bitlocker users.  I am NOT one, but would still like to get the update installed.  Also read I can copy winre.wim FROM a 'similar machine'.  I did that and it resides now in

C:\Recovery\WindowsRE   (where it came from)

on the problem machine.  The problem I am facing now is getting "The Windows RE image was not found." error.

To my knowledge ... I have never actually CREATED/MOVED/RESIZED any parition.  That did not come up in the last tutorial I tried.

If this is any help:

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             49 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            931 GB    51 MB
  Partition 3    Recovery           254 MB   931 GB
  Partition 4    System              99 MB   931 GB
```

Looks to me like recovery partition is too small for installation of the update.  I have been up and down with this tutorial and that tutorial.  The furhter I go, the more confusing it seems.  Any help is immensely appreciated.

Another weird thing.  Had the same update failure on another W10 machine but it is HOME version.  I ignored the failure for about a month .... and 'suddenly', the updated succeeded.  I'm shocked and cannot fathom how that happened.  It has not happened though on this PRO machine.

Comment: [KB5034441 fails to install in Windows 10 22H2 due to error 0x80070643](https://gist.github.com/Chester-Gillon/987093d3d59df532950af6b67b45d9cf) is my gist on the investigation into why KB5034441 failed to install on one of my Windows 10 Pro machines, and how was able to re-size the recovery partition to allow the update to install. Not sure if that is any more helpful than the other tutorials you have already seen. The Windows 10 Pro machine on which KB5034441 failed to install also didn't have bitlocker enabled.

Comment: This should be installed via Windows Update. Don't try to do it yourself.

Comment: That update installed on my Windows 10 VM earlier this year. The reason for the update failure was indeed a too small recovery partition. Either you need to make the recovery partition bigger (I suggest 1.5 GB) or backup and reinstall Windows 10. I did the latter and it has been updating ever since.

Comment: Your WinRE is way to small it should be double the size (650MB) it currently is, use the script provided by Microsoft, to accomplish that task. “Read somewhere that the update only applies to BitLocker users.” - What you read isn’t accurate

Comment: It certainly is too small.  I found that script in one of the tutorials.  I ran it, but it did not fix anything.  Maybe I did not run it right?  Pasted script into notepad and saved it as foobar.ps1   Ran it in elevated Powershell (never have run a powershell script before).  Appeared to run .... I guess.   Also trying to figure out how to get notified when I get replies.  Suggestion??
I have also provided a screen shot of MiniTool partition wizard.  Hope you can see it.  Looks like a link in original post saying "enter image description here"